# form validation codeigniter 3 with ajax always false when update data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

hi guys i have problem when update my data using codeigniter and ajax, when update data my form validation always return false.. but when insert data thats work normal. this is my code, i hope someone can help me, thx a lot..

my controller

```
 public function updateFakultas()
    {

        $id = $this->input->post('id', true);
        $fakultas = $this->input->post('fakultas', true);

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fakul', 'Fakultas', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $hasil = [
                'error' => true,
                'fakultas' => form_error('fakul', '<p class="mt-3 text-danger">', '</p>'),
            ];

            echo json_encode($hasil);
        } else {

            $this->Fakultas_model->updateData($id, $fakultas);
            $hasil = [
                'error' => false
            ];
            echo json_encode($hasil);
        }
    }
```

ajax

```
        $('#data_fakultas').on('click', '.item_edit', function() {

            var id = $(this).attr('data');
            $('#id_fakultas').val("");
            $('#fakultas2').val("");
            $('#fakultas_error2').html("");

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<?= base_url() ?>fakultas/getFakultas',
                data: {
                    id: id
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#ModalUbahFakultas').modal('show');
                    $('[name="id"]').val(data[0].id_fakultas);
                    $('[name="fakul"]').val(data[0].nama_fakultas);
                }
            })
        })


        $('#ubah-fakultas').on('click', function() {

            var id = $('#id_fakultas').val();
            var fakultas = $('#fakultas2').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '<?= base_url() ?>fakultas/updateFakultas',
                data: {
                    id: id,
                    fakultas: fakultas
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {

                    console.log(data);
                    if (data.error == false) {
                        $('#ModalUbahFakultas').modal('hide');
                        swal("Good Job!", "Data berhasil diubah", "success");
                        $('#fakultas_error2').html("");
                        $('#fakultas2').val("");

                        tampil_data_fakultas();
                    } else {
                        $('#fakultas_error2').html(data.fakultas);
                        $('#fakultas2').on('keyup', function() {
                            $('#fakultas_error2').html("");
                        })
                    }
                }
            })
        })
```

my view

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalUbahFakultas" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="UbahLabelFakultas" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="UbahLabelFakultas">Form Ubah Fakultas</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <input type="hidden" id="id_fakultas" name="id">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fakultas2">Nama Fakultas</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fakultas2" name="fakul">
                        <div id="fakultas_error2"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Tutup</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="ubah-fakultas">Update Data</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i already try to console when ajax post, its fine but i think this problem with form_validation->run()..

Answer (score 0):

you are making a silly mistake while setting validation rule.

your code

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('fakul', 'Fakultas', 'required');
```

Change to

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('fakultas', 'Fakultas', 'required');
```

Your mistaking post variable name "**fakultas**" with "**fakul**" while making an Ajax post.

Check your Javascript code

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '<?= base_url() ?>fakultas/updateFakultas',
                data: {
                    id: id,
                    fakultas: fakultas
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {

                    console.log(data);
                    if (data.error == false) {
                        $('#ModalUbahFakultas').modal('hide');
                        swal("Good Job!", "Data berhasil diubah", "success");
                        $('#fakultas_error2').html("");
                        $('#fakultas2').val("");

                        tampil_data_fakultas();
                    } else {
                        $('#fakultas_error2').html(data.fakultas);
                        $('#fakultas2').on('keyup', function() {
                            $('#fakultas_error2').html("");
                        })
                    }
                }
            })
```